# How do I optionally require a command line arguement for Ant?

Tags: command-line, ant, build-process

I'm new to ant, and I want to require a file name if something other than the default target is used, so the calling syntax would be something like this:

```
ant specifictarget -Dfile=myfile
```

I'm using the [ant contrib package](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) to give me additional functionality, so I have this:

```
<if>
    <equals arg1="${file}" arg2="" />
     <then>
        <!-- fail here -->
     </then>
</if>
```

My thinking is that if file was not specified it might be equal to the empty string. Obviously, this didn't work, and I'm not finding any examples on google or the right syntax in the manual.

So what syntax should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really need the contrib package. This is more conveniently done using built-in ant capabilities like if/unless and depends. See below:

```
<target name="check" unless="file" description="check that the file property is set" >
    <fail message="set file property in the command line (e.g. -Dfile=someval)"/> 
</target>

<target name="specifictarget" if="file" depends="check" description=" " >
    <echo message="do something ${file}"/> 
</target>
```

Comment: Was gonna write the same thing :-).  An even shorter version would be "<fail unless='file' message='set file property...' />"

Comment: +1 Thanks, David and Matt. I ended up using the short version.

Comment: Guys, do you need strictly to add the _if_ attribute in the second target named _specifictarget_?

Answer (score 4):

You've got the right idea. The

```
ant specifictarget -Dfile=myfile
```

sets Ant Properties from the command line. All you really need is

```
<property name="file" value=""/>
```

for your default value. That way if file is not specified, it will be equal to the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Since properties are not mutable in Ant, you can add this:

`<property name="file" value="" />`

This will set the property `file` to an empty string if it hasn't already been set on the command line.  Then your equality test will work as you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can use escape the value since ant just spits out the actual text when it can't do a property substitution.

```
     <if>
       <equals arg1="${file}" arg2="$${file}" />
       <then>
         <echo>BARF!</echo>
       </then>
     </if>
```